# Need to create an animated GIF in C#

Tags: c#, .net, animation, gif, .net-ngif

I have tried all sorts of soloutions, such as

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2005/05/10/3830.aspx

and

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/NGif.aspx

but none of them seem to work correctly. NGif was okay, but the resultant gif was corrupt (white pixels on first frame). And I couldn't get Rick van den Bosch's code to work at all. I'd just like some code that I could include, and have a function  CreateAnimatedGif that takes a list of images, the delay and whether to loop, and returns an Image (or a string with the filename it's written to).

But no matter what, I can't get anything to work.

Comment: IMHO, I can help  you better if you try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example]

(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

I am a strong believer in ***code clarity and simplicity***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://midimick.com/magicknet/

http://midimick.com/magicknet/magickDoc.html