# Manipulating .gif images

Tags: .net, vb.net, animated-gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create an animated gif in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196322/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-net)

How would I turn single images into animated gifs and vice versa?  Is there an existing library for such a thing?

I'm using vb.net so any .net code examples are helpful :)

Thanks if you can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google found a quick code sample [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/NGif.aspx).  This is an Animated GIF Encoder for .NET - called NGif.

Here is a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213529/need-to-create-an-animated-gif-in-c), with some more links - directed at C#, but still helpful.